# ASP.NET MVC gets recurrent requests, even though no one is making them

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I have the following ASP.NET MVC page: https://domain.azurewebsites.net/Request/Index/?email=foo@bar.com.

Upon calling this page, I prepare the visitors session in the background (it's mainly getting data from another source into the DB used for this project), and in the meantime I show them a simple page saying "Your session is being prepared" which the user may close at any time. When the preparation is done, I send the requestor an e-mail with the link to their unique session (a new link if a session for this e-mail didn't exist yet, or a link to an existing session).

It's as simple as this:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string email)
 {
        //some email and other validation
        System.Threading.Thread tr = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(CreateSession));
        tr.Start();

        return View();
 }
```

When people call this page, I log the entry into our logging database. I also log when the preparation is done successfully (and the e-mail has been sent).

Now I received a complaint from a user, that he receives a mail with a link to his unique session everyday, almost always at the exact same time, without calling the page and thus requesting his link. And indeed, both in our logging and in the mailbox used to send the links I can see that there are requests being made by his email on the times this user states, and also I see in the logging that with every one of those requests, the preparation was done successfully.

Does anyone have an idea how it is possible that this page is being called, even though no one is calling it, and how I can fix this issue? I was thinking in the direction of browser caching on the users PC, but the fact that it happens at exactly the same time doens't really point in that direction I guess...

Comment: What is the use of threading? When the thread stops? When created session will dispose?

Comment: I use threading to prepare the session for the user in the background, because this preparation can take up to 5 minutes. So the user gets the screen saying "your session is being prepared, we'll email a link to you shortly" which he can close while the session is being prepared. 

Once the session is prepared, a link to this session is sent to the user, and the thread stops. 

By session I don't mean a web session, I mean a session that is managed in the DB - there's a table "Session" which holds the session ID (which is used for every action) and an expiration time.

Comment: I can't say it will solve your problem, but the way you're handling this in general is completely wrong. A web application should never spin up new threads in an action. If you want to actually do something in the background, you should use something like Revalee (http://revalee.sageanalytic.com) or Hangfire (http://hangfire.io/). In other words, actual background processes that operate outside of the scope of your web application.

Comment: Completely agree with @Chris Pratt. You can also use azure webjobs for this. Also, on every action performed you need to mark that job or task as complete. So that it will not get picked next time.